# Как передать переменную из шаблона в плагин на вордпресс?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Есть плагин который выводит записи по определенному в нем шаблону. Нужно передать в него переменную из шаблона страницы. Думал что можно сделать это с помощью экшна, но у меня не получилось. Возможно я что то не так понял. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: _"Нужно передать в него переменную из шаблона страницы"_ -- зависит от того, что Вы под этим подразумеваете.

Comment: _(к коменту выше)_.. и каковы задачи и цель?

Comment: "зависит от того, что Вы под этим подразумеваете" - а что непонятно? Плагин выводит посты по одному шаблону. Хочу добавить в него еще один и прописать условие что бы применялся шаблон в зависимости от значения передаваемой переменной

Comment: Если Вам что-то очевидно, не значит что это очевидно всем остальным, так как Вашу конкретную проблему понимаете только Вы. Как Вы уже упомянули в самом вопросе, то у плагина могут быть определенных хуки, посредством которых это можно сделать, а может и не быть, чтобы дать какой-то конкретный ответ, нужно знать какую-то конкретику. И что значит _"передать"_? Вы уверены что под капотом у Вашего плагина есть механизм чтобы принять эту переменную и её обработать?

Comment: 1. я просто уточнил. без какой либо агрессии
2. передать переменную значит сделать так что бы ее значение из шаблона страницы подставить в условие в шаблоне плагина
3. что там есть в плагине я не в курсе. я просто знаю что хуком можно передать ее в functions.php и  подумал что можно сделать что то подобное с плагином

Comment: Ищите в документации к плагину, чего-то универсального нет. Может там есть соответствующие фильтры, может он позволяет переопределять шаблоны и тп. Просто так, Вы туда свое значение из какой-либо переменной не подставите. Вопрос слишком общий.